nginx in front of AWS ALB intermittently reports "upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream" error
I have an nginx instance sits before an AWS ALB which forwards the HTTP request to the backend target. The flow is basically like this:

nginx is doing a proxy_pass, e.g. proxy_pass http://service.example.internal
DNS resolves service.example.internal which is a CNAME to the DNS name of the AWS ALB. This CNAME is defined in a Host zone in Route 53
There are three Network Interfaces attached to the ALB, therefore the DNS resolved 3 IP addresses, for example: 10.192.10.75, 10.192.11.133, 10.192.10.45
nginx picks any of the IP addresses and make the call

However, the interesting part is that intermittently, nginx will fail to make the connection to the chosen ALB IP and generate an error message similar to the following:

[error] 41#41: *32767409 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.128.73.156, server: *.example.com, request: "GET /api/v1.0/example HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.192.10.75:80/api/v1.0/example", host: "myservice.example.com", referrer: "https://myservice.example.com/"

In the above message, the IP address in the
upstream: http://10.192.10.75:80/api/v1.0/example

is exactly one of the IP addresses of the ALB.
I Googled the similar questions and someone said that this problem could be caused by AWS ALB IP changing, since AWS ALB uses dynamic IPs for scaling. However, after checking all the configurations and the logs, I can be 100% sure that this error was not caused by ALB IP changing, because all those three IPs were there and were in In-use state bound to the Network Interfaces of the ALB.
So, is there any other possibilities that could cause this issue to occur?
Thanks!
Edit-1: Nginx configuration attached
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen               443 ssl;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "origin" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            return 200;
        }

        server_tokens        off;
        server_name          example.com;
        client_max_body_size 2G;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/json application/xml image/png image/svg+xml;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;

        resolver 10.192.0.2 valid=5s ipv6=off;

        set $upstream_api http://service.example.internal;

        location ~* ^/api/[^/]*/example {
            proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_read_timeout         120s;
            rewrite            ^(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass         $upstream_api;
        }

    }
}


Edit-2: More info about the error
Also, I can always see the following error before each of the above error:

[warn] 42#42: *32713022 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.128.73.156, server: *.example.com, request: "GET /api/v1.0/example HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/auth/user-info", upstream: "http://10.192.10.75:80/auth/user-info", host: "myservice.example.com", referrer: "https://myservice.example.com/"


show the complete nginx vhosts configuration please

Hi @djdomi, I attached the nginx config in the post, thank you.
